# sweetalert calling to an external file to display its data

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

i have sweetAlert2 using it in my website, how can i call a file inside the sweetalert2, right now i am using `window.open` to open a popup a show its contents, i want to use the `sweetalert` to show that, is this possible,

i have done the ajax part but i am not sure how ajax part will work if i do not have any input fields, just ajax that file and reload the contents in there

code i have added above

here it is

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
Swal.fire({});
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.